# Nested conditional ternary operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, conditional-operator

I have the below code, where idName is selected based on id1 or id2.

```
const getValues = async ({ id1, id2, ...request}) => {
   const id = id1 || id2;
   const idName = id1? 'uid' : 'sid';
 };
```

Now, I add another parameter "id3" and which needs to get selected when id1 is not passed in as input. But the below code throws an error. Any leads would be appreciated.

```
const getValues = async ({ id1, id2, id3, ...request}) => {
   const id = id1 || id2 || id3;
   const idName = id1 ? id3 ? ('uid' : 'sid') ? (id3);
 };
```

Comment: What should be the `idName` for `id3`?

Comment: Why is `getValues` async when it does no async work? Why is the value of `idName` just thrown away and never returned?

Comment: `const idName = (id1 && 'uid') || (id2 && 'sid') || (id3 && '3id');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getValues = async ({ id1, id2, id3, ...request}) => {
   const id = id1 || id2 || id3;
   const idName = id1? 'uid': id3? 'something-for-id3': 'sid'
};
```